# Derivatives for individual neurons in a keras neural neural network

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I am trying to get the derivatives of individual neurons in a keras feed-forward neural network w.r.t. the weights of network.

To do this, I make use of subnetworks and the built-in gradient functions of keras. For example, for neuron *k* in layer *l*, I will return a subnetwork that goes up to layer *l* with the rest of the neurons in layer *l* deleted. Then, I take the gradient of that subnetwork w.r.t. the weights in the subnetwork. (I do this for all neurons in the network.)

The problem with this is that the gradient function is actually with respect to the error or cost of the network, not the output itself, i.e. it's something similar to *Error*grad(neuron_lk)*, and you need a label for the datapoint to compute that error. I don't want that error term there.

Additionally, I feel like there is perhaps a simpler or more efficient way to do all of this. Any suggestions?

Here is my code:

**For gradient:**

```
def gradient(model,x):
    weights = model.trainable_weights # weight tensors
    ##weights = [weight for weight in weights if model.get_layer(weight.name[:-2]).trainable] # filter down weights tensors to only ones which are trainable
    gradients = model.optimizer.get_gradients(model.total_loss, weights) # gradient tensors

    input_tensors = [model.inputs[0], # input data
                     model.sample_weights[0], # how much to weight each sample by
                     model.targets[0], # labels
                     K.learning_phase(), # train or test mode
    ]

    get_gradients = K.function(inputs=input_tensors, outputs=gradients)


    inputs = [[list(x)], # X
              [1], # sample weights
              [[model.predict(np.array([x]))[0][0]+1]], # y
              0 # learning phase in TEST mode
    ]

    return get_gradients(inputs)
```

**For submodel:**

```
def get_submodel(model, layer_l, neuron_k):

    #creating submodel and pruning layers:
    submodel = deepcopy(model)
    for i in range(len(model.layers)-layer_l):
        submodel.pop()

    #getting [pruned] weight matrix:
    W = model.layers[layer_l].get_weights()[0]
    if layer_l != len(model.layers) - 1:
        Wk = W[neuron_k,:]
    elif layer_l == len(model.layers) - 1:
        Wk = W

    #adding new layer back:
    if layer_l != 0:
        submodel.add(Dense(1, activation='relu', use_bias=False))
    elif layer_l == 0:
        in_shape = model.layers[0].input_shape[1]
        submodel.add(Dense(1, activation='relu', use_bias=False, input_shape=(in_shape,)))

    #setting [pruned] weight matrix:
    submodel.layers[layer_l].set_weights([Wk.reshape([-1,1])])
    submodel.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mean_squared_error')
    return submodel
```

**final call for a single neuron (layer *l*, neuron *k*):**

```
gradient(get_submodel(model, l, k),x)
```

Thanks in advance for any input!

Comment: If you want your code reviewed you should better try on (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). A better worded question (and one more answerable here) would be "How to obtain derivatives of weights of individual neurons on a CNN in Keras"

Comment: Ah, that is helpful, thanks!